# Url rewrite with custom post type and taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, rewrite-rules

Here is what I am looking for:

```
Custom Post Type: partner
Archive: domain.com/partners/ (list all partners)
Custom Taxonomy: country
Archive: domain.com/partners/denmark/ (list all partners in a country)
Custom Taxonomy: city
Archive: domain.com/partners/denmark/copenhagen/ (list all partners in a country and in city)
Single: domain.com/partners/denmark/copenhagen/the-name-of-the-partner-post/
```

On the custom post type rewrite I have the following:

```
$rewrite = array(
    'slug'                  => 'partners/%country%',
    'with_front'            => false,
)
```

It works fin with the following:

```
domain.com/partners/denmark/
domain.com/partners/denmark/copenhagen/
domain.com/partners/denmark/copenhagen/the-name-of-the-partner-post/
```

BUT I cannot find a rewrite solution that works with:

```
domain.com/partners/
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a few ways to handle this, but I'm guessing the fact that you're using "/partners" in your taxonomy rewrites is messing things up for using "/partners" alone for the CPT.

I think I would probably use "/partners" for the CPT only, and then define a [custom rewrite rule](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/) that determines what the parameters after the various slashes correspond to.

If you take a look at the examples on the reference page, you might get an idea of what I mean. Specifically, look at the one from  Akira Tachibana on [that page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/).